# Complexity class of problems P, NP, EXP?

Tags: complexity-theory, fibonacci

the problem of calculating the n-th number of the Fibonacci sequence in which complexity class of problems belong to? I think in the class P, give me confirmation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is surely in P class using [Binet's Formula](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html) But, we can't give an exact number.

Answer (score 0):

There's [an analytic solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form), so it's O(1), which implies it's in P.